# Can Selenium webDriver Python bindings test a Ruby on Rails website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver

Can Selenium webDriver Python bindings test a website developed in Ruby on Rails ? Also will I be able to use Firebug  to know the id etc. of the webwlements of that website?  I am very new to web test automation. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can Selenium webDriver Python bindings test a website developed in Ruby on Rails ?

Yes, but if you write the tests in the code of the project if you encounter any issues you could always ask a dev who is familiar with the code base. When you use another language you're risking having a resource familiar with the language to ask.

> Also will I be able to use Firebug to know the id etc. of the webwlements of that website?

Yes you can use firebug to find the css id, xpath, etc. If you're using Chrome the web developer settings has these features built in.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter for the driver whats the underline technology powers the site under test. That being said if you want to hook up into the back end for better reporting etc it would be easier to do with the same language